# Oreo and getting battery usage stats per app

Tags: android, operating-system, battery

I thought that 8.1 was introducing an API to retrieve battery usage per app?

Is there a way to do this?

I've used `android.intent.action.POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY` but it's quite limited.